# Complex boostrtrap Grid (nesting)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am trying to figure out how to achieve the layout below with bootstrap.

Here is my code so far. I do not find a solution to put the blocks below the first cols...

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div style="height: 905px; background-color: blue;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div style="margin-top: 200px; height: 305px; background-color: blue;"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div style="margin-top: 30px; height: 370px; background-color: blue;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div style="margin-top: 30px; height: 1000px; background-color: blue;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script></body>
```

The desired layout is:

[image]

Comment: ups i forgot to put my code. Here it is.

Comment: can't be done with just plain bootstrap. you have multiple places that cant be part of one row you will have to write custom CSS

Comment: Ok.. that's what I was guessing.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the next code you can see the layout. You have to know that the :before styles are just to show you how it see. This example isn't made thinking responsive, if you want it works on mobile and table devices, you have to edit it.

Another thing is that the sixth box is out of the container, if the screen has little with, this box won't see complete.

I give to all boxes a fixed heigh to test it see like the picture.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.container .red:before,
.container .red2:before {
  background-color: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.container .red:nth-child(1):before {
  height: 200px;
}

.container .red:nth-child(2):before {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.container .red2:before,
.container .red:nth-child(2):before,
.container .red:nth-child(5):before,
.container .red:nth-child(7):before {
  height: 80px;
}

.container .red:nth-child(3):before {
  height: 75px;
}

.container .red:nth-child(4):before {
  height: 265px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-6 red"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 red"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 red"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right red"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1 red"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="red2" style="margin-left: -20%;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 red"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks René! I really appreciate your help.